# Linux Profiling

Tags: linux, profiling

I want to profile my application which is most of the time doing I/O on a USB device.

I need to see what process are running on system and what each process is exactly doing whole the time.

Following are specs about system under test:

OS: Fedora 13(stripped down version)
app language: Python/wxpython

so, can anyone guide me towards right tools/books/articles/guides?

Answer (score 2):

Use ps, time, and top.

Answer (score 2):

`iotop` and `dstat` are very very handy tools for identifying performance issues.  I recommend specifically '`dstat -af`' to find out what resource is (at any given time) the limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

That's just what [random-pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) (stackshots) is for.
It's easy to do in python using ctrl-C.
Here's a [brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468022/how-to-measure/4501805#4501805).

If you want visibility into the C code, an alternative is [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/).